# how to make modaless mfs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, modal-dialog

hi im using mfc in c++,
and i need to make it modaless,
and also i need to have a function which turn on and off the gui,
which also i dont know how to do.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to read http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/gettingmodeless.aspx and source [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/175y2765(v=VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/175y2765%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
If you mean turn off gui as do not show dialogs then just dont show it use console or hidden windows